# How can I pass connection information to a runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm having problems passing some connection info to a runnable thread(using rabbitmq, but I don't think this is specific to rabbitmq and can apply to anything).  My goal is to have a few worker threads processing some work from a queue but I don't want the overhead of opening and closing connections each time.

The code works without runnable(its actually stolen from the rabbitmq tutorials) but as soon as I implement a runnable passing a connection I get this error on doWork():
`The method doWork(Channel, String) is undefined for the type Worker`  If I remove Channel from runnable and don't send it then the program works fine but the connection information is not being passed.  What can I do?

Here's my code:

```
      //this is the standard stuff to start a connection
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            factory.setHost("localhost");
            Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
            Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

        channel.basicQos(1);

        QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
        channel.basicConsume("task_queue", false, consumer);
      //end of standard stuff       

        while (true) {
          QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
          String message = new String(delivery.getBody());

          System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");   
          doWork(channel, message); 
          System.out.println(" [x] Done" );

          channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
        }
      }
```

then:

```
  public class doWork implements Runnable{

        protected Channel channel = null;
        protected String message   = null;

        public doWork(Channel channel, String message) {
            this.channel = channel;
            this.message   = message;
        }


        public void run() {
```

Comment: Please name your classes in `UpperCase`, methods and fields in `camelCase` and static final constants in `FULL_CAPS`. Also notice that [interfaces are always adjectives and classes are nouns](http://www.iwombat.com/standards/JavaStyleGuide.html#Class%20and%20Interface%20Names).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you moved your code to a Runnable, this means you created a new class. If you want to invoke it, then you should have something like this

```
doWork work = new doWork(channel, message);
work.run();
```

But you probably want to move all that to an external Thread, which is done by:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new doWork(channel, message));
t.start();
```

Btw, classes should start with an upper-case letter, it makes the code much more readable.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll adjust my casing.   Am I wrong in seeing this as going to launch a new thread every time I select it?  What happens if(in my queue example) I only want to process 4(# of cores I have) items at once? I can set it in on the queue server but it'll do it for all my clients(even ones with more cores) is there a way to limit the number of threads I launch to a specific number?

Comment: If you want to limit the number of threads then you should look at the `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(num)`.  You just submit jobs and the pool takes care of keeping the threads at the right level.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to call a method named `doWork`:

```
 // this is a method call
 doWork(channel, message);
```

What you want to do (I guess) is something like:

```
 new doWork(channel, message).run();
```

but more likely you are trying to fork a thread there so it would be:

```
 new Thread(new doWork(channel, message)).start();
```

As an aside, you should capitalize your class names which would make it easier to see.  `doWork` should be renamed to be `DoWork` then it's easier to see the difference between method names and class names.  Method names should always start with a lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your `Worker` class you have a method `doWork(String message)` defined.  What is defined inside your `doWork` class (whose name doesn't follow Java conventions, btw), doesn't matter until you have created an instance of that class and call the method on that instance; you're trying to call a method of the `Worker` class at present.